# "Right Click" keyboard short cut for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to force myself to use as little mouse as possible and I can't find the answer to this simple short-cut anywhere! Here the the steps:

1. Open up Visual Studio. Open any C# file (or any code file I believe)
2. Point your mouse anywhere on the
   window/file.
3. Right Click

Is there a shortcut key for this so I don't have to move my hand to the mouse?

Comment: @Thomas Owens: You don't have to point your mouse at a window. For example you can move the focus to the code Window by pressing F7. Or the solution explorer window by pressing Ctr-W, Ctr-S.

Comment: Why force yourself? Keyboard, mouse and short cut are all meant for convenience/efficiency. :)

Comment: Came here from a tangential Google search, but noted that this question is _NOT about VS Code_.

Comment: If you get sent here like @conny and me by your search engine about vscode, you can change the keyboard shortcut called "Show Editor Context Menu" which by default is Shift+F10 on my setup.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Taken from [lytebyte](http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/05/29/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-right-click-context-menu/), you've got two options:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
- That nutty key on the bottom-right of a modern Windows keyboard, the [Menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)

Comment: Perfect. Using this trick also shows underscored letters we can use keyboard to access. While right click doesn't (on my computer).

Answer (score 7):

Depends on where/why you're right-clicking.

The context-menu key is on the right of the keyboard nowadays, usually between the Windows key and the Control key on the right of your spacebar. That will open the context menu wherever the current focus is (usually in the text editor).

If you're using the right mouse button just to open the refactoring tools, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (control period) to pop open the "smart tag" on any identifier. That'll get you the "generate method stub" menu item and the like.

Comment: Good suggestion with "Ctrl+." I love this key combo and use it all the time, it's SO much quicker and less fiddly than using the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Does your keyboard have the extra 'Windows' keys, ie. the Windows logo (Start key) and the one on the right-hand side of the spacebar that looks like a menu?  Cause that button on the right-hand side is the 'Context menu key'.

See the key between the right-hand side 'Windows' key and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key?
[Windows Keyboard layout](http://www.nursingstudies.co.uk/keyboard1.JPG)

If your keyboard is less than 10 years old you should have these keys, unless you have an IBM laptop or a Mac.!

Answer (score 2):

To open a new file without keyboard you can use 
      <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>  (Using Resharper)
To show up the right click menu for any part of your code. Point to the part that you want and use
      <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Normally, I like using 
      <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (Resharper again)
for getting the Navigation menu (Usage, Base, Implementation, etc)

Even better if you want to go to any Method/class/intenal/or a field, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (Again using Resharper), this will bring you a list of all that match your criteria to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want a key you can press to right click, most\many keyboards have a key between alt and ctrl that right clicks.